not found elemet in new page in robotframework
I am trying to find the value of an element on the page without loading the page, but after opening the desired page, I am quickly redirected to the login page.
[Tags]    SaveOrder
Create Session    saveOrder    ${urlAPI}${saveOrder}    cookies= ${session_cookie}     verify=True
${body}=          Create Dictionary    sub_product_id=${productID}    value=1         #value must fetch by xpath
${header}=        Create Dictionary        Accept=application/json
${response}=      POST On Session        saveOrder     ${url_api}${saveOrder}        json=${body}         headers=${header}
${bodyResp} =     Convert To Dictionary         ${response.json()}
${dataResp}=      Get From Dictionary     ${bodyResp}    data
${invURL}=        Get From Dictionary    ${dataResp}    redirect_to
${invID}=         Split String From Right    ${invURL}    https://main-api.iranicard.plzdev.ir/api/v1/factors/    1
${ID}=            Set Variable          ${invURL}[1]  #Get Invoice ID
Set Global Variable    ${invoiceID}    ${invID}[1]
${status} =     Convert To String    ${response.status_code}
Should Be Equal    ${status}    200
Browser.New page      https://main-panel.iranicard.plzdev.ir/invoice?id=${invoiceID}
sleep     120s
# Wait for the invoice page to load
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${walletBalance1}    timeout=120s

